# Monitoring of a process performance implications?

Tags: php, ajax, linux, performance, monitoring

I have 3 servers with processes that require all the CPU they can get. I let these processes write their standard output to a file

```
./run.sh > run.log
```

Would this writing slow down the process? (the ./run.sh script starts eg. a Java program and sometimes a Ruby program)

Now I want to create a web-interface that would display the output from the script while it is running. I can imagine writing a php script which refreshes every 5 seconds, creates a SSH connection to the server does and gets the run.log file.

But wouldn't that interfere with the process or slow it down? **It is really crutial that the server is able to use as much of it's power as possible.** Or are there better ways to handle this? Instead of creating an SSH connection every 5 seconds, maby a persistent connection and update with Ajax?  (security is not a requirement)

Comment: If you worry about it that much, you should not be using Java or Ruby in the first place.

Comment: It is not that crucial that I would go through the trouble of learning C :) The meat of work is also done using EclipseCLP, Java and Ruby are used to guide everything. For the moment it is the best solution given the time constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this writing slow down the process? (the ./run.sh script starts eg. a Java program and sometimes a Ruby program)

Maybe; if the process writes a lot of data, it can easily slowdown the process, because likely the process will be writing synchronously to the disk. Otherwise, you don't have to worry.

An alternative would be having a setup where the script sends the output to the machine with the web application via some kind of message service. This would avoid polling the server; whether it would be more efficient depends on the details.

A simple an efficient mechanism would be forwarding stdout to a UDP socket and have the web application listen and store temporarily those messages in a circular buffer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would there be an easy way to do this? Sending the output through a socket would be faster than writing it out? It is not that much data, every +-30 seconds it writes around 40 lines of output

Comment: With 40 lines of output every 30 seconds, I wouldn't worry about performance degradation... I though you were talking about much more data than that. To answer your question I really don't know what's faster, but sending data through a UDP socket would have the advantage you wouldn't have to poll the server, potentially making things simpler. You can create listening and sending UDP sockets easily with `ncat`.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your respons, I Googled a bit and now I'm sending the output of my process with netcat to loggly :)